# How to use a regression model for what-if-analysis?

Tags: regression, interaction, multicollinearity

I train a linear regression model on historic sensor data and controlable variables to predict a quality metric.

The R² of the final model y = b0 + b1 * x1 + b2 * x2 + b3 * x3 is quite good. Now it would be beneficial to use that model to perform what-if-analysis by changing x1, x2, x3 to see the effect on the predicted quality metric y.

It turns out that this doesn't work as expected, because of collinearity in the real system. A model with only additive effects would be needed.

Are there any approaches how to use a linear model, trained on historic data for what-if-analysis?

Comment: The model you've given is a model with only additive effects, so I don't understand the point you've made in the third paragraph.  Additionally, what you're attempting to do is likely related to causal inference and the $do$ calculus. I suggest searching for those terms to refine your question.

Comment: Right, i changed the problem description to collinearity only, interaction terms could be added manually.

Answer (score 1):

This is not so much an answer to your question as it is  an explanation of how causal inference and the $do$ calculus can help.  Let's examine a simpler model

$$ y = \hat{\beta}_0 + \hat{\beta}_1 X_1 + \hat{\beta}_2 X_2$$

Unless you've generated the data $X_1, X_2$ via a controlled experiment, the data may be correlated and the effects confounded by unmeasured variables, etc.

You're seeking to answer "what would happen to $y$ if I changed $X_2=x_2$ to $X_2=x_2 + \delta$?".  Naively, the answer would be

$$ E[y\vert X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2+\delta] - E[y\vert X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2] = \delta \hat{\beta}_2 $$

I say "naively" because $\hat{\beta}_2$ **is not the causal effect of $x_2$ on the outcome y, it is average observed trend which may be confounded**.  In order to estimate the average causal effect, you would need to compute

$$ E[y\vert X_1=x_1, X_2=do(x_2+\delta)] - E[y\vert X_1=x_1, X_2=x_2] \not\equiv \delta \hat{\beta}_2 $$

Here, the $do$ operator implies a physical intervention on the $X_2$ variable, effectively forcing it, ignoring any correlation with other variables, to its new value.  If it helps, here is a concrete example.  Assume $x_1$ is the presence or absence of a gene, $x_2$ is height and $y$ is weight.

$$ E[y\vert X_1=1, X_2=190] - E[y\vert X_1=1, X_2=180] $$

would be the average change in weight between two people with identical gene status who differ only in height by 10 cm.  Note my language here. I'm being very careful not to say that changing height forces weight to change.  However,

$$ E[y\vert X_1=1, do(X_2=190)] - E[y\vert X_1=1, X_2=180] $$

would be the change in weight if I could somehow stretch a person an extra 10 cm.  That is *completely different* since any association between height and the gene would be completely ignored.  I'm FORCING height to change, not just observing the average trend.

This may or may not be too complex for what you want. It is however the appropriate way to analyze the "what if" in your question.  I leave the $do$ calculus for you to learn more about independently.

Comment: Thanks fo your the explanation. I will take a look at do calculus. It looks a bit complicated to me when I checked the dowhy python package and in requires domain knowledge to provide the causal graph as I understood. But if there is no other solution it might be helpful.